# MLP giving inaccurate results

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, softmax

I tried to build a simple MLP with 2 hidden layers and 3 output classes.
What I have done in the model is:

- Input images are 120x120 rgb images. Flattened size (3 * 120 * 120)
- 2 hidden layers of size 100.
- Relu activation is used
- Output layer has 3 neurons

## Code

```
def model(input, weights, biases):
   
    l_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    l_1 = tf.nn.relu(l_1)

    l_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    l_2 = tf.nn.relu(l_2)

    out = tf.matmul(l_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out
```

## Optimizer

```
pred = model(input_batch, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer =   tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(rate).minimize(cost)
```

The model however does not work. The accuracy is only equal to that of a random model.
The example followed is this one:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py

Comment: How much training data are you using, how long are you training and what was the loss value after training stopped?

Answer (score 0):

You have a copy-paste typo in `def model`. First argument name is `input` while it is `x` on the next line.

Another trick to use when you suspect that model is not being trained is to run it on the same batch again and again. If implementation is correct and model is being trained it will soon learn that batch by heart yielding 100% accuracy. If it does not then it is an indicator that something is wrong in your implementation.